# Bathroom Tile over old thinset

Tags: tile, asbestos

Is it possible to use self leveling concrete over old thin set? I do not believe breaking it all up is an option as it was placed over existing asbestos tile. If the floor was cleaned properly and any loose pieces were removed could this work?

Comment: I see no reason why not, as long you count for increase in total hight

Comment: And scrape and/or vacuum any loose material before you do your new tile.  (Careful not to disturb the asbestos.)

Answer (score 2):

The self-leveling underlayment products I've used specifically allowed for this. Materials and methods are listed in the instructions. Make sure to follow them carefully and completely.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it will not work.

As long you make sure the old layer is solid.

And as long you keep in mind the increase in total hight alignment to next room.